# Passing argument to a method in callback array in add_action() - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to pass an argument (say `$arg`) to the second parameter/callback of `add_action()` using `do_action()` in Wordpress.

```
do_action( 'my_hook',  $arg);
```

the `'my_hook'` in `do_action()` will refer to the below `add_action()`

```
class My_Class {

    public function __construct () {
        add_action( 'my_hook', array( $this, 'my_method ($arg)' ) );
    }

    public function my_method ($arg) {
         some_function ($arg);
        // some code here....
    }
}
```

Note: I am not trying this in fuctions.php. Trying to modify core files. I know modifying core files is not recommended. But, I want to explore the horizons (I will return back to the home though)

Please provide a way to pass the argument into `my_method()`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hm I think this should work if you take out the `($arg)` from the add_action call.

```
class My_Class {

    public function __construct () {
        add_action( 'my_hook', array( $this, 'my_method' ) );
    }

    public function my_method ($arg) {
         some_function ($arg);
        // some code here....
    }
}

// make sure you are creating a new object so __construct() is called
$instance = new My_Class();

do_action( 'my_hook', $arg );
```

If you look at the documentation, `add_action` lets you specify the number of arguments an action accepts. It defaults to 1.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#more-information